# unexpected output in constructor calls

Tags: java, constructor

```
class SuperclassA {
    protected int superValue;                              // (1)
    SuperclassA() {                                        // (2)
        System.out.println("Constructor in SuperclassA");
        this.doValue();                                    // (3)
    }
    void doValue() {                                       // (4)
        this.superValue = 911;
        System.out.println("superValue: " + this.superValue);
    }
}

class SubclassB extends SuperclassA {
    private int value = 800;                               // (5)
    SubclassB() {                                          // (6)
        System.out.println("Constructor in SubclassB");
        this.doValue();
        System.out.println("superValue: " + this.superValue);
    }
    void doValue() {                                       // (7)
        System.out.println("value: " + this.value);
    }
}

public class Javaapp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Creating an object of SubclassB.");
        new SubclassB();                                   // (8)
    }
}
```

why is my output:

```
Creating an object of SubclassB.
Constructor in SuperclassA
value: 0
Constructor in SubclassB
value: 800
superValue: 0
```

i suppose this should be like:

```
Creating an object of SubclassB.        
Constructor in SuperclassA
value: 800
Constructor in SubclassB
value: 800
superValue: 0
```

Comment: Have you tried a debugger? Using a debugger, you can set a breakpoint on the line `new SubclassB();` and step into every function call and see the order things get executed.

Answer (score 0):

`SuperclassA`'s `this.doValue()` is calling the `doValue()` method in `SubClassB` and `value` does not get initialized until `SubClassB` is being created.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_overriding for more information.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you see `0` for the first `value` output is that the field initializer for `value` (which sets it to 800) will not be run until just before the constructor for `SubclassB` is about to be called. During the construction of `SuperclassA` (which must occur prior to the construction of the subclass,) `value` is observed in its unitialized state, which is 0.